# Why is there a difference in output?

Tags: java, c

Why is there a difference in output?

```
class Amie
{
   public static void main(String...a)
   {
       int i=5;
       i=++i/i++;
       SOP(i);
   }
}
```

OUTPUT=1

in C ---

```
void main()
{
    int i=5;
    i=++i/i++;
    printf(i);
}
```

OUTPUT = 2

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points. This explains the behaviour of such expresssions in C

Comment: `undefined behavior` and `== vs equals` are the most two duplicated questions here :_(

Comment: @Vivek27 This is the 2nd one in 2 hrs :(

Comment: This is probably a better dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402304/please-explain-why-java-and-c-give-different-answers-for-this-code

Answer (score 0):

Java standard **does** reglament how such an expression should be evaluated and there is only 1 possible answer - 1.

In case of C there is no guarantee from standard for possible optimization. You could receive 2 as well as 1 in executables generated by other compilers. So it is **undefined behaviour** in C