# Please explain why Java and C give different answers for this code

Tags: java, c

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        i = i++;
        System.out.println("value of i is : " + i);
    }
}
```

Output is : `10`

When I executed similar code in `C`, output is `11`.

Comment: Well, the difference between you expectation and what happens is clearly because your expectation of what `i = i++` does is wrong. What more is there to say? To really answer this question we need to know *why* you think the output should be 10?

Comment: The dup cited does not cover Java at all, except by passing reference and definitely does not explain the difference between Java and C with respect to this example and their approaches to undefined behavior and sequence points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With respect to `C` this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are trying to modify the same variable more than once within the same [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) on this line:

```
i = i++;
```

the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.5` *paragraph 2* says:

> **Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once** by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, **the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored**.

This is well defined in Java, which does not have the same sequence point concept that `C` does and the Java Language Specification(*[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)*) goes out of its way to ensure such operations are defined. Section [15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.7) of the JLS says:

> The **left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.** For example, if the left-hand operand contains an assignment to a variable and the right-hand operand contains a reference to that same variable, then the value produced by the reference will reflect the fact that the assignment occurred first. [...]

and section `15.7.2` says:

> The Java programming language also guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) **appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.**

Note that `C` does not specify the order of evaluation, mainly to give the compiler [better options for optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540468/1708801). From the draft standard section `6.5` *paragraph 3*:

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74) Except as specified
>   later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.**

**Update**

If you want a discussion on some of the differences in philosophy between Java and C with respect undefined behavior you have [Undefined behavior is a design decision](http://shape-of-code.coding-guidelines.com/2012/05/14/undefined-behavior-is-a-design-decision/) and [Undefined behaviour in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153843/undefined-behaviour-in-java).

Comment: Whats about c++? AFAIK the order in which the operators execute is well defined there.

Comment: @Paranaix This behavior is undefined in C++ as well section `1.9` paragraph 15 in the draft standard.

Comment: But cant it be written as `i = i.operator++()`? I know well that `i` isnt a object, but I try to explain my point of view with that pseudo code.

Comment: @Paranaix I apologize, I did not respond earlier but you are correct, in that instance right before the function is called introduces a sequence point, although the language has changed in the newer draft standards.

Answer (score 5):

This is [Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `C`. Lack of [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: This is also defined behavior in Java, where the variable's value is saved, the variable is incremented, and the old value written back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `i = i++;` post ++ will increment value after that step. But here at the moment of assigning `i++` to `i`, `i` still is `10` so you are getting `10`. But in C this may different from Java. If you use `i=++i` in `Java` code, you will get `11.`

Answer (score 0):

Java and C are different languages with different rules.  In C, the exact order in which expressions are evaluated and side effects are applied is *unspecified*; for an expression like `i = i++`, there's no guarantee that the side effect of the `++` operator will be applied before the assignment takes place.  The result will vary depending on the platform, optimization settings, even the surrounding code.  The behavior is *undefined*; the compiler can handle the situation any way it sees fit, which includes generating an unexpected result.

Java, OTOH, does specify a strict order of evaluation and that side effects are applied immediately, so the expression is well-defined.